# Why I can't change the background color of a PrimeNG orderlist component via CSS into my Angular application?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using on an Angular application using PrimeNG into my project and I am finding some difficulties trying to override the CSS of a PrimeNG component.

In particular I have an orderlist like this:

[image]

As you can see the selected item have blue as default background color. I am trying to change it to gray but it is not working.

This is my HTML code of my entire component view:

```
<p-selectButton [options]="workShiftTypes" [(ngModel)]="selectedShift" optionLabel="name"></p-selectButton>
<p>Selected Work Shift: {{selectedShift ? selectedShift.value : 'none'}}</p>

<div class="custom_sift" *ngIf="selectedShift.value == 'custom'">
  <app-custom-event-date-selector
                (notifyStartEndTime)="onChangeCustomShiftDate($event)">
  </app-custom-event-date-selector>
</div>

<div #draggable_people>

  <p-orderList [value]="people" [listStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" header="People"
    filter="filter" filterBy="name" filterPlaceholder="Filter by name" dragdrop="true">
    <ng-template let-person pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix fc-event" style="background-color: transparent; color:black !important;border: 0px !important;">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm">
                <img src="assets/img/people/person-icon.png" style="display:inline-block;float: left; margin:2px 20px 2px 2px" width="48">
                <div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{person.name}}</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="people-operations-icons">
                  <button class="btn" (click)="onClickFilter(person, $event)">
                    <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-funnel-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M1.5 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 2 1h12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-.128.334L10 8.692V13.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.342.474l-3 1A.5.5 0 0 1 6 14.5V8.692L1.628 3.834A.5.5 0 0 1 1.5 3.5v-2z"/>
                    </svg>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-orderList>
</div>
```

The list is rendered inside  this tag: **<p-orderList [value]="people" [listStyle]="{'height':'400px'}" header="People"**

Chrome developer tool show this:

[image]

So into my component CSS file (that is correctly imported into my component .ts class) I put:

```
body .ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list .ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
```

to override the default blue color defined into the **theme.css** file. But it is not working. Selecting an item it still remain blue and not grey.

What could be wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have this classes in template: `".ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list .ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight"`, you can't access them from a template-component.css

For this situation you need a global/theme css file that overrides the styles from PrimeNG.

Or you can use **deprecated** selector `::ng-deep`

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list .ui-orderlist-item.ui-state-highlight {
  background-color: grey !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked using the depracated selector but I am not understanding...
1) Why I have not this classes in template? I can see it using Chrome developer tools...so I am not understanding why the style was not applied...what am I missing?

2) What exactly is this :host and ::ng-deep selector? and why are deprecated?

3) What are the alternative solution that doesn't use these deprecated selector?

Comment: 1) dev tools show the rendered HTML, but the classes you used is inside another component that is created by PrimeNG and their are also incapsulated, thats why you cant access in your component.
2) :host is a selector for current component style, and using with deep you won't mess another components style.
3) As far as I know there is still no alternative to ::deep selector